# live audio spectrogram data

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, dataset

I am making a dataset for a neural network that takes in live audio (from my microphone) and prosesses it into spectrogram data. My problem is that I want to make a dataset for the neaural network using prerecorded audio (as I want to get sounds off the internet and use wav sound files). At the moment I cant find a library that can prosess audio data live or from a sound file, I have to use seperate libraries that prosess the sound differently.

I can make a small dataset with my live microphone and the neural net is very accurate, when I make a dataset from a sound file it is hardley accurate at all.
I'm not worried about the actual neural network as it is working as intended even with a small dataset when I use the live microphone.
I am very much new to this so I'm aware I could be making some silly mistakes.

This is my code for the neural network

```py
import librosa
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow import keras
import warnings


# Parameters (audio)
sr = 44100
n_ch = 1
n_fft = 2272  #changes how many numbers are outputted per loop
n_plot_tf = 80
n_freqs = n_fft // 2 + 1
f_max_idx = 480  # 1 < f_max_idx < n_freqs
window = np.hamming(n_fft)
amp = np.zeros((n_plot_tf, f_max_idx))
duration = 100

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="X does not have valid feature names, but MinMaxScaler was fitted with feature names")

# Load training data CSV file
train_data = pd.read_csv('D:\\lowpressuretrain.txt')
# Load test data CSV file
test_data = pd.read_csv('D:\\lowpressuretest.txt')

#define single test number
single_test_number = 6

# Extract features and labels for training data
train_features = train_data.iloc[:, 0:1137]  # Extract columns 0 to 1137
train_labels = train_data.iloc[:, 1137]  # Extract column 1138

# Extract features for test data
test_features = test_data.iloc[:, 0:1137]  # Extract columns 0 to 1137
test_labels = test_data.iloc[:, 1137]  # Extract column 1137
test_features_df = pd.DataFrame(test_features)

# Scale the features using the same scaler as before
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train_features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(train_features), columns=train_features.columns)
test_features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(test_features), columns=test_features.columns)

single_test_features = test_features_df.iloc[single_test_number, :].values.reshape(1, -1)
single_test_features_scaled = scaler.transform(single_test_features)


# Build the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation='relu', input_shape=(1137,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_features.values, train_labels.values, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=1, shuffle=True)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels, verbose=1)
print("Test Loss:", test_loss)
print("Test Accuracy:", test_accuracy)


# Define the audio parameters
sample_rate = 44100
hop_length = 512
frame_index = 1
device_index = 1


def print_spectrogram(indata, frames, time, status):
    # Convert to monaural
    x = np.mean(indata.reshape(-1, n_ch), axis=1)
    x_windowed = x * window
    X = np.fft.rfft(x_windowed, n=n_fft)
    S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(X), ref=np.max)
    S_db_reshaped = np.reshape(S_db, (1, -1))
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
    S_db_scaled = scaler.transform(S_db_reshaped)  # Apply the scaler to the spectrogram data
    prediction = model.predict(S_db_scaled, verbose=0)
    print(int(np.round(prediction, 3)))



stream = sd.InputStream(callback=print_spectrogram, channels=2, samplerate=sr)

# Start the audio stream and capture data for the specified duration
with stream:
    sd.sleep(int(duration * 1000))  # Convert duration to milliseconds
```

I have tried printing a dataset with the following code. It doesn't seem to be working though

```py
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import librosa

# Parameters (audio)
filepath = "soundfile_path"
sr = 44100
n_ch = 1
n_fft = 2272  #changes how many numbers are outputted per loop
hop_length = int(n_fft / 4 * 3)  # Adjust hop_length based on the updated n_fft
overlap = 0
n_plot_tf = 80
n_freqs = n_fft // 2 + 1
f_max_idx = 480  # 1 < f_max_idx < n_freqs
window = np.hamming(n_fft)
duration = 100
blocksize = n_fft

for block in sf.blocks(filepath, blocksize=blocksize, overlap=overlap):
    if block.shape[0] != n_fft:
        continue
    x = np.mean(block, axis=1)  # to monoral
    x_windowed = x * window
    X = np.fft.rfft(x_windowed, n=n_fft)
    S_db = librosa.amplitude_to_db(np.abs(X), ref=np.max)
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)  # makes me print infinite numbers
    # print(np.round(S_db, 3))  # print spect data while rounding the numbers
    print(", ".join(["{:.8f}".format(value) for value in S_db]), ", 0")
```